# Ubuntu 22.04 autoinstall.yaml dynamic

Tags: 22.04, autoinstall

I try to rewrite the autoinstall.yaml while the installer is runnning.

What i do is , i read a standart user-data with early_command that wget a new user-data and saved it as autoinstall.yaml.

```
autoinstall:
  early-commands:
    - wget "https......." -O /autoinstall.yaml
```

That is working BUT then the autoinstaller output an error with: an error occurred.

in my wget user-data is this:

```
autoinstall:
  user-data:
    disable_root: false
  identity:
    hostname: abc.de
    password: rootPassword
    username: root
  version: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/autoinstall.yaml` file does not include the `autoinstall:` key.

As an example, the `/autoinstall.yaml` based on your sample should contain

```
user-data:
  disable_root: false
identity:
  hostname: abc.de
  password: rootPassword
  username: root
version: 1
```